# Passing parameters to custom Deserializer

Tags: java, json, mapping, jackson, deserialization

I have json that contains multiple rows.

```
{
    "rows": [{
        "aId": 408,
        "aFrstNm": "TIM",
    },
    {
        "aId": 410,
        "aFrstNm": "BOB",
    },
    {
        "aId": 409,
        "aFrstNm": "HENRY",
    }]
}
```

and POJOs

```
public class User extends Employee {
    @JsonProperty("tableName")
    private Double aID;
    @JsonProperty("aFrstNm")
    private String aFrstNm;

    getters and setters ommitted
}

public class Employee {
}


public class Employees {
   private Collection<? extends Employee> rows;

   getters and setters ommitted
}
```

What I am trying to do is to pass the User class to a custom deserializer to be able return employees as a collection of Users that extend Employee:

```
    SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule")
        .addDeserializer(Employees.class, new JsonDeserializer<Employees>() {
            @Override
            public Employees deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext  ctxt) throws IOException {
                ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) p.getCodec();
                final Class<?> clazz = (Class<?>) ctxt.getAttribute("mappingClass");
                final JsonNode jsonNode = (JsonNode) mapper.readTree(p).get("rows");
                Employees employees = new Employees();
                Collection<Product> rows = new ArrayList();
                if (jsonNode.isArray()) for (final JsonNode objNode : jsonNode) {
                    boolean isValueNode = objNode.isValueNode();
                    String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(objNode);
                    Product product = (Product) new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, clazz);
                    rows.add(product);
                    System.out.println(jsonNode);
                }
                employees.setRows(rows);
               return employees;
            }
        });
    mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

the variable clazz (final Class clazz) attribute should contain the class a parameter.  I so far have been unable to find a mechanism that allows this.  DeserializationContext seems to be promising but I have not been able to make this work.  Any suggestions on using DeserializationContext or some other way to pass parameters?

Tnx.

Comment: *Why* are you trying to pass that as a parameter?  What will this achieve?

Comment: The use case is that a REST PUT with path  /employees/user along with the data is sent to a service.   The POJO's are build from JSON schemas.  The data sent is going to change frequently.  I am looking for a way to have Jackson map the object from the name supplied by REST service PathVariable {employee}

Comment: I found that throwing a wrapper around the above code then passing the parameter through the wrapper did the trick.